# Get sum of ord values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure I completely understand the `ord` procedure in Python. If `ord` turns a `char` into a `number`, why can't I get the sum of a string as depicted in the code?

```
e = 'dogs'
for i in e:     
   h = ord(i)     
   return h     
print sum(h)
```

First I get a syntax error stating that the return is outside the function, no matter where I put the return.

Comment: to use `return`, it needs to be in a function

Answer (score 1):

You get syntax error because you can't use `return` outside a function.

```
In [4]: e = 'dogs'

In [5]: sum(ord(i) for i in e)
Out[5]: 429
```